# Customizing an OAuth access token for app

Tags: api, connected-apps, oauth

I am  setting up External Identity for authentication into a custom application.

Provisioning access to various features within the application using custom object records that will be assigned to the contact.

What we would like to do is customize the OAuth access token that identity sends to the application to include which features they have been provisioned. Is it possible to include this custom information in the OAuth token itself rather than requiring the application to perform a separate API call back for this data?